# How to download a file in samsung active watch

Tags: javascript, tizen-web-app, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-studio

I am a beginner with wearable applications and working in Tizen studio using HTML/CSS & JS. I am currently working on an application that collects the sensor data from the Samsung wearable (galaxy active) watch. I would like to store the data in a file and download that file. Going through a few of the online resources. I understood that downloading a file is not possible on a wearable device. Could anyone suggest a way to store the files somewhere so that I can access them later?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To store a data in filesystem for using it later, you can use [Filesystem API](https://docs.tizen.org/application/web/api/5.5/device_api/wearable/tizen/filesystem.html). If you are using Tizen 5.0+ please refer to [this guide](https://docs.tizen.org/application/web/guides/data/file-system/#manage-files-and-directories) otherwise [this guide](https://docs.tizen.org/application/web/guides/data/file-system-old/#managing-files-and-directories).
If you want to store data in app's private storage (no access to other apps) you can use a virtual path '*wgt-private*' and create files in this directory.